# Get Currency from format VBA

Tags: vba, excel

we are facing a little problem right now.
We would like to get the currency from a cell and write it in the cell to the right.
The code we got so far is the following:

```
Public Sub GETWährung()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 6 To 9
Dim w As String
w = Right(Cells(i, "I"), 3)
Cells(i, "I").Offset(0, 1).Value = w
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is, that the currency isn't included in the cell, it's a custom format.
For example:
[image]
On the left you can see the formated cell, on the right the output is shown.
We appreciate any help.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: I don't get why the custom format is a problem as you can get the format with the NumberFormat property. Then you'll probably get an expression from which you can get the currency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `w` will get the last three characters of the *value*. The currency code is not part of the value but of the *representation*. If you want to get the text that is displayed in a cell, you can use something like `cells(i, "I").text` - however, I will not recommend to do so.

If you just want to have the same format, you can use

```
For i = 6 To 9
    Cells(i, "I").Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = Cells(i, "I").NumberFormat
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks a lot never thought of the difference between between .value and .text. --> No it's totally clear!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the format of those cells, add this line (the format is just an example):

```
Cells(i, "I").Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Or outside of the loop:

```
Range("E:F").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's easier to copy the format of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same would be to use the Style method, which would format the cell as Currency depending on your Regional Settings, as below:

```
Cells(i, "I").Offset(0, 1).Style = "Currency"
```